# Azure DF REST API not offsetting requests correctly

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline in ADF which pulls data from an API source via a REST API connection and sinks it into a SQL database table. the API has a 100 row limit per request. I have added this limit=100&offset={dynamics variable{ for this which works however the issue I have is the requests are only pulling through 1 row of data on each request.

I have analysed the results and it looks like its reading the 100 rows but only pulling through the first one. then reading lines 2-101 and pulls through the second line. and so on.

Is this a config issue? can anyone clarify this or recommend a setting in Azure pipelines to amend in order to set the amount of rows collected per request?

**UPDATE** I have added some screenshots as per request.

[screenshot of API link with limit & offset config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Sncl.png)

[Pagination rules for API offset. just done a max query of 2 for example purposes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d2z5.png)

[Client Preview which comes out in order. take note of ID numbers in order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBlfI.png)

[Output of debug. only 2 lines copied instead of 100 x 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yMh4.png)

[query testing as you can see only 2 lines and also not in order. its like its pulled the first row and 101st row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUEIW.png)

Comment: did you check the configuration of your REST API source in the ADF pipeline to Make sure that you're setting the limit parameter to 100 and that the offset parameter is being correctly calculated from a dynamic variable?

Comment: Can you provide your REST API dataset configurations and Pagination configurations in ADF?

Comment: Hi @1SaeedSalehi & rakesh, I have added some screenshots to clarify your questions. this is my first time using APIs so there might be something i´m misunderstanding.